# Remove elements inside nested JSON based on condition

Tags: javascript, json

Below is my JSON object in which I want to remove the `groupType` from the group that dosen't have trips.ie.,`trips.length===0`.And also want to remove the entire client object if all the trips array is empty for that particular client object..

```
let fruitsArray= [
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mango"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "C"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Apple"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    "trips": [
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 62,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "C"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 95,
                "name": "Banana"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "A1"
                    },
                    "trips": [
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 62,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 63,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 65,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001,
                                "orderId": 22
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The code that I have tried returns all the elements with 0 `groupType`..

```
 let finalArray = fruitsArray.map((group) => {
     return group.group.filter((trip) => {
        return trip.trips.length > 0;
     })                    
 })
```

Comment: you also want to remove the whole fruit if there are not trips in it?

Comment: yes @JuHwon.The whole fruit

Comment: Instead of map you could use reduce and conditionally push the object if the group doesnt have trips

`let finalArray = fruitsAray.reduce((res, group) => {
                   return res.concat(group.group.filter((trip) => {
                        return trip.trips.length > 0;
                    }) || []);
                }, [])`
I havent tested the code. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Please learn about what JSON is and is not, and revise your question accordingly. Here you are not talking about JSON, you're talking about JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
Alternatively you can also use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

I wrote both examples beneath.

```js
let fruitsArray= [
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mango"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "C"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Apple"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    "trips": [
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 62,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "C"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 95,
                "name": "Banana"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "A1"
                    },
                    "trips": [
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 62,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 63,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 65,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001,
                                "orderId": 22
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];


var filteredFruits = fruitsArray.map((fruit) => {
  fruit.group = fruit.group.filter((group) => group.trips.length);
  return fruit;
}).filter((fruit) => fruit.group.length);

console.log(filteredFruits);

// alternative example with reduce
var reducedFruits = fruitsArray.reduce((prev, next) => {
  next.group = next.group.filter((group) =>  group.trips.length);
  return next.group.length ? prev.concat([next]) : prev;
}, []);

console.log(reducedFruits);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var fruitsArray= [
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mango"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "C"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Apple"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    "trips": [
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 62,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "C"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                },
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    "trips": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 95,
                "name": "Banana"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "groupType": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "A1"
                    },
                    "trips": [
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 62,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 63,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "trip": {
                                "id": 65,
                                "deliverySlotId": 900000000000001,
                                "orderId": 22
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]


    for(var i=0;i<fruitsArray.length;i++){
     var currentFruit = fruitsArray[i];
     var currentFruitGroups = currentFruit.group;
         var foundTrip =false;

         for(var j=0;j<currentFruitGroups.length;j++){

                    var currentTrips = currentFruitGroups[j].trips;

                     if(!currentTrips.length){

                currentFruitGroups.splice(j,1);
                j--;
             }else{
                foundTrip = true;
             }
                }
          if(!foundTrip){
            fruitsArray.splice(i,1);
            i--;
          }
    }
    console.log(fruitsArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/485ue5zs/1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
let finalArray = fruitsArray.reduce((p, n) => {
  const gt = n.group.filter(g => g.trips.length);
  return gt.length ? p.concat({fruit: n.fruit, group: gt}) : p;
}, []);
```